# Default selected value in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Im trying to set default value of `ComboBox`. I'm using binding in layout and I'm not sure how bind it right. Here is my `viewModel`:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Sklady sklady = null;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public Sklady Sklady
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sklady;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sklady = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Sklady");
        }
    }
}
```

How I am set data to `viewModel`:

```
private void comboBoxSklad_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //get some data
    prijemWindow.viewModel.Sklady = sklady;
    prijemWindow.viewModel.Sklady.skladID = prijemWindow.viewModel.Radky.radky[index].SKLAD;
}
```

My `viewModel` use this class to get values:

```
[DataContract]
public class Sklady
{
    [DataMember]
    public List<Sklad> sklady { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String skladID { get; set; }

    public class Sklad
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string CODE { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is current `xaml` code:

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBoxSklad" Loaded="comboBoxSklad_Loaded" ItemsSource="{Binding Sklady.sklady}" DisplayMemberPath="CODE"
        SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedItem="{Binding Sklady.skladID}"/>
```

Data are binded into `ComboBox` correctly and I can see data from `sklady` `List`. But I would like to set the `ComboBox` default value to `skladID` value. How can I do it?

**ANSWER**

With answer from `Klaus Byskov Pedersen` I get it work... First, I use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`... Then, I ininialize `Sklady` in constructor `prijemWindow.viewModel.Sklady = new Sklady();prijemWindow.viewModel.Sklady = new Sklady();` and at the end, changed lines :

```
sklady.skladID = prijemWindow.viewModel.Radky.radky[index].SKLAD;
prijemWindow.viewModel.Sklady = sklady;
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem`.

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBoxSklad" Loaded="comboBoxSklad_Loaded" ItemsSource="{Binding Sklady.sklady}" DisplayMemberPath="CODE"
    SelectedValuePath="ID" SelectedValue="{Binding Sklady.skladID}"/>
```

When using `SelectedItem` the bound item would be of type `Sklady`, not `string`.

**EDIT**`

```
prijemWindow.viewModel.Sklady = sklady;
prijemWindow.viewModel.Sklady.skladID = prijemWindow.viewModel.Radky.radky[index].SKLAD;
```

You have a `NotifyPropertyChanged` when you set `viewModel.Sklady` but at the time this is fired, you have not yet set the `skladID` so try changing the order of those two statements.

Comment: Thanks for reply! This is really helpful... but still not working.. My guess is that problem is in `ItemsSource="{Binding Sklady.sklady}"` and `SelectedValue="{Binding Sklady.skladID}"`... but I'm not sure how to set these two values right to get it work

Comment: You need to initialize your list (`Sklady`) somewhere, e.g. in a constructor. You'd better move your `Sklad` class out of `Sklady` class, and the latter one actually doesn't make sense. Do you have a single `skladId` for a list of `Sklad`s? Why?

Comment: @mechanic It's because, when `Window` is open, the `List` is load from database... but default value is known before and I can propably pass it as parameter, or do this (my question)

Comment: OK, it looks like I get it work, I will edit my question and accept you answer.. Thanks both of you guys